# Maven+GWT Get provided dependencies on the class path when in dev mode

Tags: maven, gwt

I am using maven and gwt to create a standard war. I have lots of dependencies which I have set as provided because my deployed production instance will provide them. However, I am also developing the app in GWT using dev mode and I really need to be able to utilize these dependencies at runtime when doing dev, but then not have them compiled into my war.

I have considered creating a separate maven module which would simply aggregate all these dependencies and give them runtime scope, and then run my dev mode from that context. However this really introduces a lot of overhead that I would prefer not to manage.

This seems like a pretty common problem, does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you use as production server (tomcat or something else?) and what as development server (GWT internal or something else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to use maven profiles: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

I created one for 'dev' and one for 'prod'. The dev one includes all my dependencies while the prod one only includes what I want to put in my war.

I can compile just for prod by doing

`mvn clean install -P prod,\!dev`

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer you want, but I guess It would be best to have the dev environment mirror the prod environment as closely as possible.

Hence I would suggest you provide your dependencies in dev mode as you do provide them in production.

Even better, you could move those depencies to a local Nexus repository. This way you can retrieve those dependencies from the same repository, whether you are in dev or prod.
This actually is the "elegant" way of doing it.

Comment: Rats, you are right, I did read the question incorrect, so my comment doesn't make sense... I will delete my comment.